# facebook page_fan check query incomplete result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I made a FB app for page.

and check the user likes the page by the app.

I use two kinds of API. and they work well.

1. FB.Data.query('SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=$pageid and uid=$userid')
   and check number of rows.
2. FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '$pageid',uid:'$userid' })
   and check it returns 'true'.

but some users appeal to our page. (

They already like our page. but they still handled as not a fan.

Actually API returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the new Graph API call to see if you get better results

`http://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/PAGEID?access_token=UserAccessTokenWithUserLikesPermissionsEnabled`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug about this. You can see it here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/344295515590822?browse=search_4f5f3563d780d9449526693

More than 1 month later Facebook does not fixed it.